# Redmine Open issue by email. Attachment is missing

Tags: email, attachment, redmine

Im using Redmine 2.3.0 server. 
Server configured to check for new emails on IMAP server (using chron service).
When i try to open new issue by sending email i cant see any mail attachments in newly opened issue.
I send email to redmine. In mail i define project and tracker.

Project: newproject
  Tracker: Bug

I add text file as attachment to email.
After some time i can see new issue opened in project "newproject" in tracker "Bug", but text file attachment is missing.I tryed to send emails in HTML and in Plain format, result is the same.
Im sure its some kind of configuration error, but i dont know where to start looking for the porblem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found an answer here.
http://www.redmine.org/issues/10721